# Unable to display items in listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am relatively new to android and am trying to display some statistics in a ListView. 
Based on the option selected in the spinner a list is generated in my StatsModel.java class (whose controller is StatsController.java). I looked around at other questions concerning errors in getting ListView to display but I could not find the solution to my problem.

Here is the code for the activity trying to display the list:

-I used the Toasts to make sure that the list in StatsModel was actually being updated

-stController.getCurrentList() returns the current list from statsModel.java

StatsActivity.java

```
public class StatisticsActivity extends Activity {

    //private TwoColStatsAdapter statsListAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> statsListAdapter;
    private String mClickerName;
    private StatisticsController stController = new StatisticsController();
    final ClickerListController clController = new ClickerListController();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistics);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        mClickerName = i.getStringExtra("clickerName");
        stController.setClickDateList(clController.getClickers().get(mClickerName).getClickTimes());
        stController.clearStats();

        /*
         * STATS_SPINNER ------------------------------------------------------------------------
         */
        Spinner statsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stats_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                R.array.stats_spinner, R.layout.stats_spinner_item);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.stats_spinner_item);
        statsSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        statsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                    View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                stController.clearStats();
                switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    stController.setHourlyStatistics();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stController.getCurrentList().get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stController.setDailyStatistics();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stController.getCurrentList().get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    stController.setWeeklyStatistics();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stController.getCurrentList().get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    stController.setMonthlyStatistics();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stController.getCurrentList().get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                statsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });

        /*
         * STATS_LIST --------------------------------------------------------------------------
         */
        final ListView statsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
        /*statsListAdapter = new TwoColStatsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.two_column_list, stController.getCurrentList());
        statsList.setAdapter(statsListAdapter);
        statsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });*/
        statsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stController.getCurrentList());
        statsList.setAdapter(statsListAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.statistics, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_statistics.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StatisticsActivity" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/stats_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:prompt="@string/stats_spinner_prompt"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stats_spinner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not sure what I am missing here but I'm curious if it has to do something with the fact that the list item is defined as a function: stController.getCurrentList() . But I don't think that's the issue because I have tried defining a local list and getting it to fetch the currentlist but it still did not display said list. Let me know what I am missing... Thanks.

feel free to point me elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

try to select the ui element for display the text:

```
statsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stController.getCurrentList());
```

Comment: i added that and it doesn't seem to change anything, unfortunately